# How to use Picasso to read image from InputStream

Tags: android, picasso, okhttp

I get a InputStream by using `response.body().byteStream()`

How to use Picasso to load image from `InputStream`?

Comment: https://medium.com/@jpardogo/requesthandler-api-for-picasso-library-c3ee7c4bec25#.9jxt8oq94

Answer (score 1):

use a Custom Picasso Downloader . you have to create custom class and  just implement Downloader(picasso) in your class and define the load method without exposing the functionality in the API directly.

```
public class DropBoxThumbDowloader implements Downloader {

private final DropBoxInteractor mDropBoxInteractor;

public DropBoxThumbDowloader(DropBoxInteractor dropBoxInteractor) {
 mDropBoxInteractor = dropBoxInteractor;
}

@Override
public Response load(Uri uri, boolean localCacheOnly) throws IOException {
 InputStream in = mDropBoxInteractor.getThumbnailStream(uri.toString());
 return new Response(in, false, -1);
}
}
```

call like this

```
Picasso picassoInstance = new  Picasso.Builder(context.getApplicationContext()).downloader(new DropBoxThumbDowloader(dropBoxInteractor)).build();
```

custom load method will return a Response (which accept an InputStream or Bitmap argument in his constructor) that will be handle for Picasso.

finally

```
picassoInstance.load(path).into(imageView);
```

for more details

[Custom Picasso Downloader](https://medium.com/@jpardogo/custom-picasso-downloader-d34d97cc28fc#.2j4ufdgn5)